# Simple Basic Grails Form Validation Needed

Tags: java, forms, validation, grails-2.0

Good Day

i am trying to configure a form for validation in grails  and i am having trouble with it. here is my class i want to validate with the respective html form:

```
@grails.validation.Validateable
class CatUser {

transient springSecurityService

String username
String password
String firstname
String surname
String email
Date ets
boolean enabled = true
boolean accountExpired
boolean accountLocked
boolean passwordExpired

static transients = ['springSecurityService']

static constraints = {
    username blank: false, unique: true
    password blank: false
    firstname blank:false, nullable: true, maxSize: 45
    surname blank:false, nullable: true, maxSize: 45
    email blank:false, nullable: true, maxSize: 45
    ets nullable: true
}

static hasMany = [catFbPosts:CatFbPosts,
    userRole:CatUserCatRole]

static mapping = {
    password column: '`password`'
    version false
}

Set<CatRole> getAuthorities() {
    CatUserCatRole.findAllByCatUser(this).collect { it.catRole } as Set
}

def beforeInsert() {
    encodePassword()
}

def beforeUpdate() {
    if (isDirty('password')) {
        encodePassword()
    }
}

protected void encodePassword() {
    password = springSecurityService.encodePassword(password)
}}
```

My Form:

```
 <div class="col-md-6">

    <label>New user:</label>
    <g:form autocomplete="off" uri ="/admin/users/save">

        <div  class ="form-group">
            <br/>
            <label>Full Name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" style="width: 250px">
        </div>


        <div  class ="form-group">
            <label>Surname:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="surName" style="width: 250px">
        </div>
        <div  class ="form-group">
            <label>Email:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" style="width: 250px">
        </div>
        <div  class ="form-group">
            <label>Username:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="userName" style="width: 250px">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>User Role:</label>
            <select class="form-control" style="width: 250px" name="catRoleId">
                <g:each var="item" in="${catRoles}"> 
                    <option value="${item.id}">${item.authority}</option>
                </g:each>
            </select>&nbsp;
        </div>
        <div  class ="form-group">
            <label>Password:</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" style="width: 250px">
        </div>
        <div  class ="form-group">
            <label>Confirm Password:</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="cpassword" style="width: 250px">
        </div>
        <div  class ="form-group">
            <button type="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </g:form>
</div>
```

How would i go by validating for null values and making sure that password == confirmed password?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to add custom validator to your constraints block. Refer this link in grails documentation : http://grails.org/doc/2.3.4/ref/Constraints/validator.html

I guess, this will still not do a client side validation for you, which you would need to handle separately using javascript.

Comment: Thanks that did it.client i used the required field in html which i think is part of the bootstrap pack